# How to change the input tag's response to addEventListener('change')?

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, addeventlistener

I take text form the user with an html input tag.  When the user types a character into the input element, I want to `console.log` the text they have just typed; it would look like I am `console.log`ing for each letter.  I attempted this by adding an event listener for `'change'` on the `input` tag.

To demonstrate what I mean, I have simplified my problem in the code below...

`<input type="text" id='userInput' placeholder='enter characters here'/>`

In JS script:

`text = document.getElementById('userInput');
 text.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('hello world');
});`

I chose the `'change'` event because I thought that typing text into an `input` tag element would equate to changing that element, such that every time the user types into the `input` element, it logs 'hello world'.

However, the `'change'` event for the `input` element is not what I expected. What actually happens is that 'hello world' is not logged until you hit 'enter' inside of the `input` element (ie a `'change'` event for a div might look different than a `'change'` event for a button).

I have been experimenting with this inside of Firebug, and I was looking at the `addEventListener` and `change` documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change), and have read that the change event listens to various tags differently.

**Does anyone know a way to modify the `input` change event for `addEventListener` to register actual text changes, not only just when someone hits enter inside `input`?**

or else

**If I cannot specify the `'change'` event for `input`, does anyone know of another way to `console.log` each character as it is typed into `input`?**

Comment: try `onchange` instead of `change`

Comment: @Abbath - Nope. If you add the event handler inline, in the html then `onchange` is correct. However, if you add the event using JS, then `change` is appropriate. I.e: `<input onchange='someFunc()'/>` _or_ `<input id='someId'/>` with some extra js: `document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener('change', someFunc, false);` - The latter method is preferable for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the ref you have linked to on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Change is fired when:

> When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not
>   commited (e.g. after editing the value of  or

And according to this again on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

*Change:*

> An element loses focus and its value changed since gaining focus.

This means that only does the focus is lost, but the value should also have changed. If you do not change anything the `change` will not be fired.

**In order to observe changes in an `input`, you could use `input` event.**

From MDN again: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an
>    or  element is changed.

You can see that using this snippet below. On `change` you have to `tab` out of the `input` to see the value whereas on `input` the value can observed on every *input* on the `input`. You could also use `keyup`, but *input* is the way to do it.

***Snippet:***

```js
text = document.getElementById('userInput');
resultChange = document.getElementById('result-change');
resultInput = document.getElementById('result-input');
resultKeyup = document.getElementById('result-keyup');

text.addEventListener('change', function() {
    resultChange.innerText = text.value;
});

text.addEventListener('input', function() {
    resultInput.innerText = text.value;
});

text.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    resultKeyup.innerText = text.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id='userInput' placeholder='enter characters here'/><hr />
<h3>On change</h3><p id="result-change"></p><hr />
<h3>On input</h3><p id="result-input"></p><hr />
<h3>On keyup</h3><p id="result-keyup"></p>
```

***Note***: handling `input` event is better for such scenarios.

.

Answer (score 1):

You should try listening to the 'input' event instead of 'change'.

```
text = document.getElementById('userInput');
text.addEventListener('input', function() { console.log('hello world'); });
```

'keyup' is also very good, but if you press and hold a button, console.logging will happen only when you release it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on KeyUp then look at the value inside http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

You can specify a min length before checking the text.  May not be exactly what you after but may be a start

or you can use onchange http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. **change event**  - fired only when input lose focus, and the string value is different then it was before.
2. **key up** - you can use the key up event:

   **In HTML:**

   <element onkeyup="myScript">

   **In JavaScript:**
    object.onkeyup=function(){myScript};

   **In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:**
    object.addEventListener("keyup", myScript);

   Live example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeydown_onkeyup